# AttributeError: module 'st_gcn.feeder' has no attribute 'Feeder_newdataset'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I am trying to run a github repository for a new dataset. For this, I added a new dataset file in a similar way to the other datasets to the module that reads in data.

However, when I run the script, I get an error that says:

AttributeError: module 'st_gcn.feeder' has no attribute 'Feeder_newdataset'

```
project
├── feeder
│   └── feeder.py
|   └── feeder.pyc
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── __init__.pyc
│   └── tools.py
|   └── tools.pyc
│   └── feeder_olddataset.py
|   └── feeder_olddataset.pyc
│   └── feeder_newdataset.py
│   └── __pycache__
    │   ├── feeder.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── feeder.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── feeder.cpython-35.pyc
    │   └── feeder_olddataset.cpython-35.pyc.pyc
```

When I run the project, the cache is not updated with the new dataset, I also tried to compile all project files using python3 -m compileall -b project

I wonder why I get this error when I have added the class attribute for the new dataset. Does it have anything to do with the pycache?? How can I update this file to include the new dataset?

Edit:

I have double-triple checked all names, basically the code fails when it checks if a component is there:

```
def import_class(name):
    components = name.split('.') #name: st_gcn.feeder.Feeder_newdataset
    mod = __import__(components[0]) #components:
    for comp in components[1:]:
        mod = getattr(mod, comp) #comp: 'Feeder_newdataset'
    return mod
```

I suppose it fails because mod = import__(components[0]) this line can't find Feeder_newdataset attribute using __init

Comment: I dont think there is any problem with cache. But I recommend you to check the module st_gcn.feeder. The attribute my be not present in the new dataset or you have to rename it

Comment: I have double-triple checked all names, basically the code fails when it checks a component is there: def import_class(name):
    components = name.split('.') #name: st_gcn.feeder.Feeder_newdataset
    mod = __import__(components[0]) #components:
    for comp in components[1:]:
        mod = getattr(mod, comp) #comp: 'Feeder_newdataset'
    return mod

Comment: I suppose it fails because mod = __import__(components[0]) this line can't find Feeder_newdataset attribute using __init__

Comment: Ok, silly me, it turns out the __init__ file has some imports as well (I am using a github repo): from .feeder_newdataset import Feeder_newdataset I added this line and all solved. thanks for the comment though